# Which DNS registrars will hide my WHOIS information?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, domain-registrar, whois

Whilst browsing [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/704/how-can-i-hide-whois-information), some of the answers mentioned that certain registrars will replace your whois information with their own. Can anybody provide details on which registrars offer this service?

Comment: I think you're getting mixing up registrar (Verisign, etc) with DNS Hosting (GoDaddy, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The many and varied companies offering this service appear to be well summarised by this [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=domain+whois+private+registration).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, anyone who offers Private Registration will 'hide' your information. That is still really just a thin veil of security, for US based registrars at least, as a subpoena will make them open up fairly quickly.

Comment: Fortunately, junk-mail marketers don't have subpoena powers (yet). The main reason I would use private registration is to reduce the registration renewal snail-mail and spam that I get. It can also be useful to delay revealing new products or companies, etc., while something is in development.